# What is the most accurate way of building a Perceptron using only NumPy?

Tags: neural-networks, python, history, perceptron, numpy

For context, I am trying to write a bunch of neural network programs using no other packages besides NumPy for educational purposes. I am trying to make them as simple as possible, i.e. removing the features that might help training or testing, but which technically aren't supposed to be there.

I am currently writing a Perceptron program, and it seems everywhere I look, it is implemented differently. The program I have written works, I am more concerned about whether or not it is accurate to what a Perceptron is (again, this is for learning purposes). For example: some people seem to use an activation function and others don't- does the Perceptron use an activation function? I know it will function either way, but which is *correct?*

Here is the code I have right now. Please correct any and all mistakes I might have.

````
##### Imports #####
import numpy as np

##### Perceptron Class #####
class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_epochs, learning_rate):
        # Hyperparameters
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.num_epochs = num_epochs

        # Network
        self.weights = np.zeros(input_size)
        self.bias = 0

    # Forward Propogation
    def forward(self, input):
        layer_output = np.dot(input, self.weights) + self.bias
        return layer_output

    # Back Propogation
    def backward(self, error, input):
        self.weights += self.learning_rate * error * np.array(input)
        self.bias += self.learning_rate * error

    # Train
    def train(self, inputs, labels):
        # Iterate Epochs
        for _ in range(self.num_epochs):
            # Iterate Pairs of Inputs and Labels
            for input, label in zip(inputs, labels):
                # Predict
                prediction = self.forward(input)

                self.backward(label - prediction, input)
    
    # Test
    def test(self, inputs, labels):
        # Iterate Pairs or Inputs and Labels
        for input, label in zip(inputs, labels):
            # Predict
            prediction = self.forward(input)

            # Print
            print(f'Input: {input}, Prediction: {prediction}, Label: {label}')

# Initialize Perceptron
perceptron = Perceptron(input_size = 2, num_epochs = 1_000, learning_rate = 0.01)

##### Training #####
training_inputs = [[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]]
training_labels = [1, 0, 0, 0]
perceptron.train(training_inputs, training_labels)

##### Testing #####
testing_inputs = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
testing_labels = [1, 0]
perceptron.test(testing_inputs, testing_labels)```
````

Comment: If you wish to have more than one layer (MLP) then you must use an activation function or multiple layers have no value since it simplifies to a single linear transformation matrix.

Comment: I'm looking at your update in the backpropagation...  Are you sure you want to implement the update in that way?  Just thinking about it, it feels like it will have a tough time converging.

Comment: In response to your first comment: This is supposed to be a regular Perceptron, not a Multi-Layer Perceptron.

Comment: In response to your second comment: I'm not sure- is this correct? It does converge, albeit not well, but I assumed that was because of how basic a model this is.

Comment: Please, edit your post to put your **specific** question in the title so that it's clearer what your main specific question really is. Thanks. Right now, "Perceptron w/ NumPy" is not a question and it's also not specific. Also, note that each post should contain only one question. If you have more, ask each in its separate post.